# How to make google visualization pie chart slice round edges

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, pie-chart

I want make chart something look like this one i made the pie chart slices the only problem where i'm stuck that to make the pie chart edges round

[image]

```js
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    
    var data = [
      ['Task', 'Hours'],
      ['Gas',  6.5],
      ['Gas',  20],
      ['Gas',  8.5],
      ['Gas',  7],
      ['Gas',  7],
      [null, 50.0]
    ];
    
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i][0] !== null) {
        total += data[i][1];
      }
    }

    var numberFormat = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
      pattern: '#,##0.0',
      suffix: '%'
    });

    var dataTable = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      if (dataTable.getValue(i, 0) !== null) {
        dataTable.setFormattedValue(i, 1, numberFormat.formatValue(((dataTable.getValue(i, 1) / total) * 100)));
      }
    }
    
    var opts = {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      pieSliceBorderColor: 'transparent',
      legend: 'none',
      tooltip: { trigger: 'none' },
      pieSliceText: 'value',
      pieSliceTextStyle: {color: '#14121F',  fontSize: 14 },
      pieHole: 0.01,
      chartArea: {left:40,top:70, bottom:0, right:40, width:'100%',height:'100%'},
      slices: {
        [data.length - 2]: {
          color: 'transparent',
          textStyle: {color: 'transparent'}
        },
        0:{offset: 0.1, color:'#6BE2FF'},
        1:{offset: 0.1, color:'#4F9FE3'},
        2:{offset: 0.1, color:'#FFFFFF'},
        3:{offset: 0.1, color:'#EB2027'},
        4:{offset: 0.1, color:'#ACACBD'},
      },
      pieStartAngle: 270,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(dataTable, opts);
  }
```

```css
body {background: #000}
.piechart {width: 500px; height: 500px}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart" class="pie-chart"></div>
```

Comment: I can't see any such formatting in the google documentation so I guess we have to alter the resulting svgs. Is that your understanding?

Comment: @AHaworth No I'm not sure how to alter the svg if you able please help me thanks for advance and for your comment :)

Comment: Maybe using masks?

Comment: @AHaworth yeah i google a bit about masks but I'm not sure how to use them in my case